# What are the advantages of Light Application objects

Tags: sobject, licenses, data-model, light-application-object

I was hoping that the introduction of "Light Application object" would do something about the data storage of junction objects, but it doesn't seem to do anything about it.

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=dev_object_def.htm&siteLang=en_US) seems limited to why I would use a "Light Application object", what are the advantages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce offers Force.com Light App Licenses that can access up to 10 Light Application Objects for a little bit cheaper than the Force.com Enterprise App License. You can find out a little bit more [in the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm&language=en_US) but it's best to talk to your AE about licenses that you may need.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need objects just for storage of data  and your business needs don't care about OWD for that object or have sharing .In this case you prefer light objects .

Light objects will involve no additional logic to manage sharing table and these won't support BULK API.

Comment: ok, but why wouldn't I just use regular objects for that? what are the advantages for me, for using light objects

Comment: I don't care that much if I find the objects in the sharing settings, as long as I don't do anything with it, who cares that sharing, bulk and streaming is enabled, when you choose just to ignore it and don't use it?

Comment: Ok so think from SFDC perspective .when you create normal objects they need to manage sharing for that internally .The share table needs to have record created and deleted frequently due to sharing rules and role hierarchy .When you keep your objects light then they don't have to worry about those algorithms.You don't care but SFDC at back end has to take care of each and everything

Comment: I understand it from an SFDC perspective, but salesforce doesnt seem to care about junction object storage (as the extra storage needs to be paid for of course => extra turnover), the day they care about me, I will care about them. Quid pro quo

Comment: Does it mean that platform sharing doesn't work all together? No implicit access for master-detail relations or rollup via role hierarchy? What is the default behaviour for sharing then? Does it mean my light app users will see only their own objects regardless the OWD?  Does it imply that the objects the users have access to should have owd public R/W to keep consistency with full salesforce licensed users?